# Make dot float on the table header

Tags: html, css

I am wondering how to make a dot for example here [https://gyazo.com/b757f6e984c19f7f4fc433f8147a5103](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CTkd.png) float on top like that I don't understand how I would do this I have tried position absolute and putting it in the which is in the tbody and it has not worked. Here is my code:

```
<tr>
                                <th scope="row">
                                    <i class="active"></i>
                                    <p>magic</p>
                                </th>
                                <td>magic</td>
                                <td>magic</td>
                                <td>
                                    <p>magic</p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <p>magic</p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="dropdown">
                                        <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                                            <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
                                        </button>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                                            <li><a href="#"><i class="material-icons"></i>Start</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#"><i class="material-icons"></i>Stop</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#"><i class="material-icons"></i>Delete</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
```

Comment: You can use [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) to display it above all other content. What CSS have you tried so far? Because I only see HTML...

Comment: @TomUdding I mean I only put position:absolute; and the whole thing disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .box {
            width: 80%;
            height:40px;
            background: red;
            z-index: 1;
            position: absolute;
        }
        .dot {
            width: 25px;
            height: 25px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background: green;
            top: 20%;
            right: 0%;
            transform: translate(50%);
            position: absolute;

        }
    </style>
</head>

<div class="box"><div class=dot></div></div>
```

basicly you need to have a dot that should float out of the div right?
In this case, you just need to set `position: absolute;` then set in what side the dot should be, for example if you want a dot just like in the picture you need to set the `right: 0%` but it will still be inside the div, so add `transform: translate(-50%, 0%)` and it will do the job if you have question just comment, hope i solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Please See here, you might be looking for this.

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/qM6rnLCEtgG3TQkxQjOe?p=preview

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Ip Address</th>
      <th>Created</th>
      <th>DataCenter</th>
      <th>Tags</th>
      <th>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">More_vert
                                          <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Start</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Stop</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Delete</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="position:relative;padding-left:20px;">Name_xxx
      <div class="circle"></div></td>
      <td>123.168.1.40:8080</td>
      <td>12-10-2010</td>
      <td>ABC_XXX</td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio">
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

here get an example `table` code. Hope you helpful.

https://jsfiddle.net/rafalito1989/d6pxf26x/